# How do you add a field in the form of field_name_id without the system throwing an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I try to add a field in the form of field_name_id, rails migration throws an error stating that the table field_names does not exists which is true. However, I need to create the field anyway. How do I make this happen?

Comment: is your form related to model. if it is related to model object. you need to have all fields as columns in table and model name as table. If you want to have form without model attribute. user form_tag rather than form_for

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem was that my app included a gem called 'schema_validations'. This gem auto generates certain constraints. One of which is you can't create any fields that end in '_id' if that field can't reference another table. For instance if you wanted to create a field called 'car_id' you would need to have a table called 'cars'. You can override this feature by as follows:

add_column :[table_name], field_name_id, foreign_key: false